# How to Use Swagger with Ocelot in Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, api-gateway, ocelot

I want to showcase all my endpoints of an API Gateway in Swagger. For gateway, I have used Ocelot with Asp.Net Core 2.1 but Ocelot's documentation says it does not support Swagger. Anyhow, if anyone can give suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2):

I have already investigated the approaches to achieve this. For now if you are not going to re-invent the wheel with custom your own implementations, then the [MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot](https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot/blob/master/README.md) package is the option to go with. Please follow readme file provided by link above. It covers all aspects of using that package.